# Travelling to Italy, with my EU national

Tags: visas, italian-citizens

I have a question, I am planning a trip to Italy in 4 weeks, but I am confused about my documents. I used to live in Italy (for 18 years, I have pakistani nationality) and my mother is an Italian citizen. I have a "Permesso a Soggiorno".

My mom moved permantly to the UK 1 year ago, because of work and I joined her too. I got a residency card (family member of eu citizen). Can I travel with my Mom with my residency card ? Or with Permesso di soggiorno ?

We're going only for a week.

Answer (score 1):

A valid permesso di soggiorno and your passport are all you need to enter the Schengen area without a visa. But if your residence permit is a *carta di soggiorno di familiare di un cittadino dell'Unione* then you must be traveling with or joining that EU citizen.

Comment: Okay, thanks for replying. So when I go to Italy I basically need to show my Permesso di soggiorno (it isn't europeo but a normal one, and it's still valid) and not the residency card ?  I have the UK's residency card too, I was confused, I didn't know which one to show.

Comment: When traveling to Italy, you show the documents which allow you to enter Italy. So you have a regular residence permit from Italy and an EEA family permit from the UK? That bit was not clear in your question.

Comment: Sorry, English isn't my first language. Yes, I have a regular residence permit from Italy and EEA family permit from the UK. Thank you for your help !

Comment: In that case, yes, you can travel to the Schengen area without a visa and without family members. But you must be traveling with or joining the EU family member to return to the UK.